# How notify Listview inside DialogFragment from its Adapter?

Tags: android, listview

`Listview` with `CursorAdapter`, i want to notify it on `onClick` event below .

**CursorAdapter**

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
Button button;
TextView text;
final MainActivity mainActivity ;
HistoryDialogue historyDialogue ;


public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
     mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    historyDialogue = new HistoryDialogue();

}


@Override
public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.historylist, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final int pos = cursor.getPosition();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.SaveRunning_Name.NAME));
    text.setText(body);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // this for delete only items in history list by getting cursor position then use it to get number of ites row
            // in database finally delete it ...

            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning_Name.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
            c.moveToPosition(pos);
            int position_column =c.getColumnIndex(Contract.SaveRunning_Name._ID);
            int position = c.getInt(position_column);
            String delete_save = Contract.SaveRunning_Name._ID + " = " + position + ";";
            int srun = resolver.delete(Contract.SaveRunning_Name.CONTENT_URI, delete_save, null);
            updateEntries();

        }
    });

}
public void updateEntries(){
    mainActivity.addEntries(0,0,true);
}
```

}

**DialogFragment**

```
public  class HistoryDialogue extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ListView list ;
Cursor c;
HistoryAdapter adapter;
History history ;
Button button ;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    history = (History) activity;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setCancelable(true);
    getDialog().setTitle("History");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history,null);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    c = resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning_Name.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), c, 0);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setChart(position);
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view ;
}



public void setChart(int position) {
    Cursor cursor;
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    cursor = resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int HIGH_COLUMN = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.SaveRunning.HIGH);
    int high = cursor.getInt(HIGH_COLUMN);
    int LOW_COLUMN = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.SaveRunning.LOW);
    int offset = cursor.getInt(LOW_COLUMN);
    int limit = high-offset ;
    history.limits(limit,offset,false,false);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Cursor cursor;
    Cursor running ;
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    cursor = resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

    ContentResolver solver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    running = solver.query(Contract.Running.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null && running!=null) {
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int HIGH_COLUMN = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.SaveRunning.HIGH);
        int offset = cursor.getInt(HIGH_COLUMN);
        running = resolver.query(Contract.Running.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        running.moveToLast();
        int id = running.getColumnIndex(Contract.Running._ID);
        int LAST_RUNNING_ID = running.getInt(id);
        int limit = LAST_RUNNING_ID - offset;
        history.limits(limit, offset, false, false);
        dismiss();
    }
}


interface History {

   public void limits(int limit,int offset,boolean state,boolean back);
}
```

}

**How can i achieve that ?**
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use broadcast receiver to notify fragment
OR create callback method to notify fragment
1]create interface and implement it on your fragment
2] pass its object in adapter and use that object to notify fragment

//code example

```
public interface ICallback {

    void onClick();

}
```

// HistoryAdapter

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
//your code

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
iCallbackInstance.onClick();

        }
    });

}
```

**EDIT**

// In HistoryAdapter

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
ICallback iCallbackInstance;
public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, ICallback instance;) {
    super(context, c, flags);
     mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    historyDialogue = new HistoryDialogue();
iCallbackInstance = instance;

  }
}
```

//HistoryDialogue

Use

```
adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), c, 0, HistoryDialogue.this)
```

instead of

```
adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), c, 0)
```

Comment: i am asking about how notify change ... i used interface as you describe and i get null pointer exception if notify listview or even use setAdapter methode

Comment: have you pass callback instance from fragment to adapter?

Comment: i implement in HistoryDialoge class ICallback.onClick{list.notify() }

Comment: have you pass callback instance from fragment to adapter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88057/discussion-between-error-and-prachi).